# Sending Array of Objects to MongoDB Atlas using node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, web-development-server

I am connected to my database using node.js.
Now I want to send some data to the database which is as follows:

> **data**

```
const service=[
    {ServiceChoseByUser:'Cleaning',PriceForService:'100'},
    {ServiceChoseByUser:'Painting',PriceForService:'300'},
    {ServiceChoseByUser:'Electrician',PriceForService:'400'},
    {ServiceChoseByUser:'Plumbing',PriceForService:'50'},
    // may be increased as the number of services selected by the user.
}
```

My schema is described as :

> **Schema.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    service: [
        {
            id: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  unique: true
            },
            ServiceChoseByUser: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  unique: true,
                  lowercase:true
            },
            PriceForService: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  lowercase:true,
                  unique: true,
           },
       },
    ]
});

let Service = mongoose.model('service', serviceSchema);

export default Service;
```

And my controller of data is :

> **controller.js**

```
import Service from ".Schema.js";


export const sendService = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const serviceByUser = req.body;
        console.log(serviceByUser);
        const newService = new Service(service);
        console.log(newService);
        await newService.save();
        console.log('Service data stored');
        res.send(200 + 'Service data stored')
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(500 + ' Error occured');
        console.log('Error: from service controller ', error.message);
    }
}
```

The app is connected successfully to the database. But when I am sending data to the database, it always shows
**Error: from service controller  E11000 duplicate key error collection: HouseDeck-Cluster.services index: services_1 dup key: { services: null }**

I checked for that by using **console.log()** as you can see in **controller.js**. When I am displaying the data it shows the data is correct but when I do **console.log(newService)**.
It always shows
**{ _id: new ObjectId("6234720c80a5f440ade88d24"), service: [] }**

It states that something is wrong with the schema. I tried various things like:

> **Already Tried These For Schema**

```
1. service=[Object]

2. service=[
       {
          id:String,
          ServiceChoseByUser:String,
          PriceForService:String
       }
    ]
 
3. service=Array

4. service={
      type:Array
     }

5. service=[
      {
          type:Object
      }
   ]

6. // already provided above
```

I tried many things, also searched for it, read the documentation but I couldn't find any solution.

**Please help**

Answer (score 1):

You have indicate in your schema that all fields are unique.

So, all data you insert in all fields **must** be unique.

Try modifying your schema like this:

```
const serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            id: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  unique: true
            },
            ServiceChoseByUser: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  lowercase:true
            },
            PriceForService: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  lowercase:true
           }
});
```

And then insert your datas with something like this:

```
newService.insertMany(service);
```

Comment: No, its not working just tried. Still getting same error.

Comment: Have you delete an recreate you collection ?

Comment: Youn can check indexes of you collection with compass or with atlas.

Comment: I also tried deleting my collection but u can see after when I pass the data by my schema it returns null so it doesn't matter if I delete the collection the element it inserts contains **service=[]** hence it sends null which I don't want

Comment: now it is storing like _id
:
623489e35e5ab2d299e93bdb,
service
:
Array,
__v
:
0 and service is not expanding means it is still null

Comment: The main problem is when i created the newService = new Service(service) it always return null.

Comment: The problem is certainly how you pass you data to Mongoose.

Comment: Have you try inserting data with ``insertMany``?

Comment: yes, and it is saying insertMany is not a function. Also, I want to add that the problem is arriving in the schema it is returning null and I was trying everything. Now the data is stored to the database but the service contains **service: Array**

Comment: It is working now the error was in the naming. I thought that it is a variable name that doesn't matter we can change it while passing data to functions but the error was in the name of the data that I was passing to the controller function. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ok, don't hesitate to check response and upvote!